# python efficient group by

Tags: python, dictionary

I am looking for the most efficient way to extract items from a list of dictionaries.I have a list of about 5k dictionaries. I need to extract those records/items for which grouping by a particular field gives more than a threshold T number of records. For example, if T = 2 and dictionary key 'id':

```
list = [{'name': 'abc', 'id' : 1}, {'name': 'bc', 'id' : 1}, {'name': 'c', 'id' : 1}, {'name': 'bbc', 'id' : 2}]
```

The result should be:

```
list = [{'name': 'abc', 'id' : 1}, {'name': 'bc', 'id' : 1}, {'name': 'c', 'id' : 1}]
```

i.e. All the records with some id such that there are atleast 3 records of same id.

Comment: aren't they both the same? Also what is T? Do you mean at least 2 common keys?

Comment: Hey! I've edited the question. Hope its more clear this time.

Comment: what happens if a you have dicts that overlap?  A simple way would be sort and group by key

Comment: I have all 'name' fields unique. the 'id' fields on the other hand are not.

Comment: How are they unique if they are all the same key? Are they only two keys?

Comment: I'm trying sort and group by, not sure if its the most efficient.

Comment: Just wanted to know if sort and group by is indeed the best option. And yes, my data is huge.

Comment: That makes no difference, I still don't quite get your problem, what are the actual keys in your dict like? Do you have name and id or can id be any string? Are you grouping by value to key or what exactly?

Comment: There is a list of dictionaries. Each dictionary has and 'name' which is a file sha and 'id' which is an integer. I need to extract records (dictionaries in this case) with same 'id' and frequency > T. Is it clear now?

Comment: Then use a defaultdict and group by value

Comment: Just so you know 5k dictionaries with two keys would not really be considered a large dataset

Comment: This one is a sample. It will get a lot larger with lot more keys. Thanks for the info anyway. Also, there is a lot of complex processing involved before this step. It took the system around 10 minutes to generate the dataset.

Comment: well using a dict grouping is `0(n)` but obviously takes memory to store the dicts but unless we are talking gigs of data you will be fine

Comment: Cool. Good to know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l = [{'name': 'abc', 'id' : 1}, {'name': 'bc', 'id' : 1}, {'name': 'c', 'id' : 1}, {'name': 'bbc', 'id' : 2}]
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain
d = defaultdict(list)
T = 2
for dct in l:
    d[dct["id"]].append(dct)

print(list(chain.from_iterable(v for v in d.values() if len(v) > T)))
[{'name': 'abc', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'bc', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'c', 'id': 1}]
```

If you want to keep them in groups don't chain just use each value:

```
[v for v in d.values() if len(v) > T] # itervalues for python2
[[{'name': 'abc', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'bc', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'c', 'id': 1}]]
```

Avoid using list as a variable as it shadows the python list type and if you had a variable `list` then the code above would cause you a few problems in relation to `d = defaultdict(list)`

Comment: I like your use of a defaultdict, its nice that you can put in a default value like a `list` and append to it.. pretty cool +1

Comment: @JohnRuddell,  you can also use it with a lambda to get nested dicts `defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))`

Answer (score 1):

to start out I would make a dictionary to group by your id

```
control = {}
for d in list:
     control.setdefault(d['id'],[]).append(d)
```

from here all you have to do is check the length of control to see if its greater than your specified threshold

put it in a function like so

```
def find_by_id(obj, threshold):
    control = {}
    for d in obj:
         control.setdefault(d['id'], []).append(d)

    for val in control.values():
        if len(val) > threshold:
            print val
```

Comment: This is what the OP wanted, but yea a default dict would be easier... slipped my mind :/

Comment: You return the first match in your loop, not sure that would be what the OP wants. `for key in control.values()` would also give you the values which is what you want. Also maybe change list to something else or that may be the OP's next question

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yup you're right, the op would only want the values() and I just changed it to print instead of return incase there are more

Comment: You can also change the if else to `control.setdefault(d['id'],[]).append(d)`, it will either create the first pairing or append to the existing key

Comment: wow thats pretty cool! I'm trying to learn more about python by answering questions since I haven't used it that much, thats a good one :)

Comment: The beauty of python, a little goes a long way!